# MongoDB on CentOS 9

Tags: mongodb, centos

I just took a VPS server with CentOS 9 to develop an API.
I installed:

- Apache/2.4.57 (CentOS Stream)
- PHP 8.0.30
- MongoDB (mongod) 7.0.4
  MongoDB installed with no problems, I can create users, databases and fill tables.
  The problems come when I try to query the DB after a POST request. This is the PHP code

post_handler.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header("Content-Type: application/json");

// Check if the request method is POST
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Receive POST data
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $userId = $data['userId'];
    $key = $data['key'];

    // Replace "myapiUser" and "yourPassword" with the actual MongoDB username and password
    $username = "myapiUser";
    $password = "yourPassword";

    // Connect to MongoDB with authentication
    $client = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://${username}:${password}@localhost:27017");

    // Specify the database and collection
    $database = "myapi";
    $collection = "api_keys";

    // Query MongoDB to check authentication
    $filter = ['user_id' => $userId, 'key' => $key];
    $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);
    $cursor = $client->executeQuery("$database.$collection", $query);

    // Check if authentication is successful
    if ($cursor->count() > 0) {
        // Authentication successful, return the desired value
        $result = "Authentication successful. Your value: This is the protected 
content.";
        echo json_encode(['result' => $result]);
    } else {
        // Authentication failed, return an error or unauthorized response
        http_response_code(401);
        echo json_encode(['error' => 'Authentication failed']);
    }
} else {
    // If the request method is not POST, send an error response
    http_response_code(405);
    echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Method Not Allowed'));
}
```

When I try to POST this:

```
{
  "userId": "test_user",
  "key": "4a7f8c2b9e1d6f0a3b8c7e4f2d9a1c6b"
}
```

I get this error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class &quot;MongoDB\Driver\Manager&quot; not found in /var/www/html/myapi/post_handler.php: 20
Stack trace:
#0 {main
}
  thrown in <b>/var/www/html/myapi/post_handler.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
```

Also testing the php with the following files, doesn't show any MongoDB module in the PHP settings:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

In php.ini I have the correct lines:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules"
extension=mongodb.so
```

I re-installed MongoDB with no results and tried both with direct call (like in the example) and with mongo libraries (with composer).
I don't know anymore what to try..

Comment: Have you tried to restart apache `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service`?